# Duck typing with otherwise useless statements (remotely Pythonic)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, duck-typing

The below will raise a TypeError for floats.

```
from math import factorial

def divide_factorials(a, b):
    return factorial(a) / factorial(b)

>>> divide_factorials(6.1, 5)
*** ValueError: factorial() only accepts integral values
```

That's perfect until I want to incorporate an optimization.

```
def divide_factorials(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return 1
    return factorial(a) / factorial(b)
```

Now I've lost my TypeError from floats where stop == start.

```
>>> divide_factorials(3.3, 3.3)
1
```

I could get my TypeError back with isinstance, but that requires my knowing exactly what will and will not work in factorial (or any other function I might be calling). It's tempting to do something like

```
def divide_factorials(a, b):
    # duck type first
    factorial((a + b) % 1)
    if a == b:
        return 1
    return factorial(a) / factorial(b)
```

This seems more robust, but less obvious. For (I'm sure) good reasons, I haven't seen this pattern before. What's the best reason not to do it?

I could dress it up with assert or try/except, but

```
assert factorial((a + b) % 1) is not None

# or

try:
    factorial((a + b) % 1)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError
```

seem, if anything, a bit MORE cryptic.

Comment: "incorporate an optimization". Have you tested how long `return factorial(a) / factorial(b)` takes to execute? Is this in a tight loop? "Premature optimisation...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed quite cryptic to call a function that is meant to perform calculations for the sole purpose of making a type validation. It makes the intention of the code unclear, and therefore makes the code un-Pythonic.

I would simply repeat the same explicit type validation if it's important. Moreover, the right way to optimize factorial division is to *not* call a factorial function, but to iterate from the divisor plus one to the dividend and aggregate the product instead:

```
def divide_factorials(a, b):
    if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in (a, b)):
        raise TypeError('divide_factorials() only accepts integral values')
    product = 1
    for i in range(b + 1, a + 1):
        product *= i
    return product
```

Comment: factorial((5.5 + 4.5) % 1) will indeed raise a ValueError. This is the kind of surprise I'm trying to avoid by duck typing. But I do take your point that it's unclear.

Comment: Ah indeed I forgot that `5.5 + 4.5` still results in a floating number. I've removed that point from my answer then.

Comment: You seem to be requiring that all inputs are floats, not that all inputs are integers.

Comment: @user2357112 Oops that was obvious. Not sure what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: This does require a  >= b. But I'll accept this as the most explicit and obvious pattern for such a function.